# QuickBooks API ignoring TrackQtyOnHand field?

Tags: php, quickbooks-online

I am trying to add an inventory item using the QuickBooks PHP SDK. I specify TrackQtyOnHand, the starting inventory and inventory start date, but these fields appear to be ignored?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

thanks!

Here is the request:

```
    IPPItem Object
(
    [Name] => Product Name
    [Description] => ProductDesc
    [Active] => 1
    [SubItem] => 
    [ParentRef] => 
    [Level] => 
    [FullyQualifiedName] => 
    [Taxable] => 1
    [SalesTaxIncluded] => 
    [PercentBased] => 
    [UnitPrice] => 17.54386
    [RatePercent] => 
    [Type] => Inventory
    [PaymentMethodRef] => 
    [UOMSetRef] => 
    [IncomeAccountRef] => IPPReferenceType Object
        (
            [name] => Sales of Product Income
            [type] => Account
            [value] => 80
        )

    [PurchaseDesc] => 
    [PurchaseTaxIncluded] => 
    [PurchaseCost] => 4.24000
    [ExpenseAccountRef] => IPPReferenceType Object
        (
            [name] => Cost of sales
            [type] => Account
            [value] => 81
        )

    [COGSAccountRef] => 
    [AssetAccountRef] => IPPReferenceType Object
        (
            [name] => Inventory Asset
            [type] => Account
            [value] => 82
        )

    [PrefVendorRef] => 
    [AvgCost] => 
    [TrackQtyOnHand] => 1
    [QtyOnHand] => 10
    [QtyOnPurchaseOrder] => 
    [QtyOnSalesOrder] => 
    [ReorderPoint] => 
    [ManPartNum] => 
    [DepositToAccountRef] => 
    [SalesTaxCodeRef] => 
    [PurchaseTaxCodeRef] => 
    [InvStartDate] => 2015-03-01
    [BuildPoint] => 
    [PrintGroupedItems] => 
    [SpecialItem] => 
    [SpecialItemType] => 
    [ItemGroupDetail] => 
    [ItemAssemblyDetail] => 
    [ItemEx] => 
    [Id] => 
    [SyncToken] => 
    [MetaData] => 
    [CustomField] => 
    [AttachableRef] => 
    [domain] => 
    [status] => 
    [sparse] => 
)
```

And the response:

```
    IPPItem Object
(
    [Name] => Product Name
    [Description] => ProductDesc
    [Active] => true
    [SubItem] => 
    [ParentRef] => 
    [Level] => 
    [FullyQualifiedName] => Product Name
    [Taxable] => false
    [SalesTaxIncluded] => false
    [PercentBased] => 
    [UnitPrice] => 17.54386
    [RatePercent] => 
    [Type] => Service
    [PaymentMethodRef] => 
    [UOMSetRef] => 
    [IncomeAccountRef] => 80
    [PurchaseDesc] => 
    [PurchaseTaxIncluded] => false
    [PurchaseCost] => 4.24
    [ExpenseAccountRef] => 81
    [COGSAccountRef] => 
    [AssetAccountRef] => 
    [PrefVendorRef] => 
    [AvgCost] => 
    [TrackQtyOnHand] => false
    [QtyOnHand] => 
    [QtyOnPurchaseOrder] => 
    [QtyOnSalesOrder] => 
    [ReorderPoint] => 
    [ManPartNum] => 
    [DepositToAccountRef] => 
    [SalesTaxCodeRef] => 
    [PurchaseTaxCodeRef] => 
    [InvStartDate] => 
    [BuildPoint] => 
    [PrintGroupedItems] => 
    [SpecialItem] => 
    [SpecialItemType] => 
    [ItemGroupDetail] => 
    [ItemAssemblyDetail] => 
    [ItemEx] => 
    [Id] => 15
    [SyncToken] => 0
    [MetaData] => IPPModificationMetaData Object
        (
            [CreatedByRef] => 
            [CreateTime] => 2015-07-19T07:02:57-07:00
            [LastModifiedByRef] => 
            [LastUpdatedTime] => 2015-07-19T07:02:57-07:00
            [LastChangedInQB] => 
            [Synchronized] => 
        )

    [CustomField] => 
    [AttachableRef] => 
    [domain] => 
    [status] => 
    [sparse] => 
)
```

Comment: Just a guess, but perhaps you should use `true` instead of `1`?

Comment: Hey Raphael: Thanks, I tried that, but it doesnt make a difference :(

Comment: Okay, it was worth a shot. I noticed that taxable was set to false even though the request was a `1`, but active was set to true when the request also sent a `1`. Good luck with your issue.  If you find the answer, please post your answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable Track Quantity on Hand in your company setting->Sales tab?

Comment: Hey Nimisha, thanks for your response. Yes, I did set Track Quantity on Hand. Any other ideas?

Comment: Hello nimisha, How can i add sales information in any service product